# Getting a mapping for the shuffling of a dataset

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit-learn's `shuffle` function to shuffle a dataset. However I would like to know the the mapping of the shuffling. For example given a dataset `D` and suppose I shuffled it, then I want to know what was the old index of an instance. Is there a quick way to do that? Like to provide a dictionary that maps the current indices to old indices?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with scikit-learn but I think you can shuffle list of dataset indices (i.e. list containing numbers 0..len(dataset)-1) and then re-index a dataset using the shuffled list. Hope it makes sense.

Something like:

```
from random import shuffle
dataset = ["1", "2", "3"]
indices = range(len(dataset))
shuffle(indices)
shuffled_dataset = [dataset[i] for i in indices]
```

after executing of this code indices list maps new index to an old one. E.g. if indices[0] = 2 then the element 0 in shuffled_dataset is element 2 in dataset.

The provide code doesn't use scikit-learn but it should be possible to apply the same idea using methods and classes from scikit-learn